# Problema para abrir localmente un aplicacion web en angular 2

Tags: angularjs-2.0, npm

Buenas, soy nuevo en esto y en el trabajo se esta creando una web app, y quiero abrirla localmente para asi puedo hacer cambios locales sin modificar nada de la original. Y al realizar el 'ng serve' me dice que ejecute el 'npm install', y al ejecutarlo me aparece el siguiente error: 
Como puedo ejecutarlo localmente?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: por favor verifica tu package.json

Comment: @JackNavaRow O mejor aún, que añada el código de ese fichero en la pregunta, todo parece un problema de conflicto de dependencias

Comment: puedes tambien agregar el error que se aloja en el log!